# Send ctrl+c to close ping request in JAVA

Tags: java, linux, ping

I have a strange case, we want to collect ping (in linux machine) response, it works well if we specified ping count, however, for those endless ping, in normal case, we will use ctrl + c to stop them, then you will get a summary in linux.

However, I find it is not work if I do it in JAVA side.

My basic idea is start up a process with JAVA, then send a ping www.google.com with this process, after that, I try to send a ctrl+c (\003) to stop this process and get summary info, however, nothing happens after I send ctrl +c

After checking it a little bit, I found before ping command finishes, all of other command will just hold until it finish, so that I dont have any opportunity to close this process, if I do it with destroy, then I will lose the stream info (Summary info)

Thanks in advance.

Br,
Tim

Comment: I dont think your suggestion solve my problem, I dont want to capture this ctrl c, what I want to know is if there is a way to send a ctrl+c to my existing java process.pls remove the minus 2 if you dont have better suggestion.

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted you, also, you can only downvote once so there isn't even a way for me to remove both...

Comment: got it, we can just let it go, thanks for your reminder anyway, based on this, I got my answer finally :)

Answer (score 2):

Do you know the PID of the ping process?
If so, you could send the SIGQUIT signal to recieve the statistics. Afterwards you could kill the process.

See [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/143845/check-ping-statistics-without-stopping) on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it tomorrow, just now I just try to send this one "INT" and it works.

Comment: Thanks, it looks good and similar with my way, I will play this also tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got a answer after a few try, this solve my problem
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("kill -s INT -9 -P 5904");